# Execute another awk from awk file

Tags: awk

Is it possible to execute another awk file from a awk file? Using an awk file I need to execute all awk files in a current folder. Is it possible to do such operations in awk?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. You'll need to use the `system()` function. I'm assuming you only want to run these scripts once. If so, you can add them to the `BEGIN` block of your wrapper script:

```
BEGIN {
    system("awk -f ./script1.awk")
    system("awk -f ./script2.awk")
    system("awk -f ./script3.awk")
}
```

If you have a large number of scripts that need to be executed, you can use a `for` loop. Do make sure that your wrapper script isn't in the same directory as all the other `awk` scripts you'd like executed, or it will be included in the glob of `awk` scripts...

```
BEGIN {
    system("for i in *.awk; do awk -f \"$i\"; done")
}
```

Comment: What is the point in calling an `awk` process from a shell that does nothing but calling a shell to run commands in? Instead of `awk 'BEGIN{system("for i in *.awk;do awk -f \"$i\";done")}'` you could also just run `for i in *.awk;do awk -f "$i";done` or even something like `ls *.awk | xargs -L1 awk -f`...

Comment: @sg-lecram: Yes you could, but this was an `awk` question. Perhaps the OP needed to perform other processing and `awk` was the right tool for the job. Never parse `ls`.

Answer (score 6):

1) Yes.
2) Don't.

awk is a tool for processing text.
shell (or whatever passes for it on your OS) is a tool for invoking commands and manipulating files and processes.

Guess which one you should use to execute all the awk commands in your file system?

If you tell us what your bigger problem is and your OS we can guide you.

Comment: What I need to do is just call one awk file and  execute multiple awk files which are in some folder.

Comment: But why do you want to call awk to execute the awk scripts? Awk's a text-processing tool, not an OS. Can't you just execute the awk scripts from the shell (or other OS equivalent) that you want to call this top level awk script from directly rather than having shell call awk to call shell to call awk?

Answer (score 2):

It is suggested to use `system` function.

Answer (score 0):

A common use for system is using it to do something with an output file just created by the awk script. It may not work unless you first close(outputfile) before calling system.