# If an awk IF is met, do another awk

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

Very new to awk and bash.  I am trying to complete an analysis on a log file.  The file contains a time value, that I would like give a min and max value for, but I need to complete this only for a specific url string that is found in the log.

Below is an example of the data:

```
[rootawk]# cat testdata.txt
123 192.168.1.1 edge 20 /url/test/1
123 192.168.1.1 edge 10 /url/test/1
123 192.168.1.1 edge 30 /url/test/1
123 192.168.1.1 google 70 /url/test/3
124 192.168.1.1 edge 25 /url/test/3
124 192.168.1.1 google 15 /url/test/3
```

I can run and awk command of the testdata.txt that only selects certain criteria:

```
awk '{if ($1 == 123 && $5 == "/url/test/1") {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 }}' testdata.txt
```

I can also run a Min Max awk to give me the min Max of the testdata.txt (part2)

```
awk '(NR==1){Min=$4;Max=$4};(NR>=2){if(Min>$4) Min=$4;if(Max<$4) Max=$4} END {printf "The Min is %d ,Max is %d",Min,Max}' testdata.txt
```

However, I would like to be able to do is run the MinMax (part2) on the output of the search criteria (Part1).

So The response would be in this case:

Number of /url/test/1  = 3 with a Time; Min: 10 Max:30

I am not sure how best to approach this.

I found this link, but it is not clear how I run this against a logfile. (this will be set to $1 in bash script)

[Execute another awk from awk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512072/execute-another-awk-from-awk-file)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `Min` and `Max` to the empty string, then update `Min` and `Max` on lines that match the filter criteria. In your `END` block, exit early if `Min` is still the empty string it was initialized to. (Either both variables are the empty string or neither one is.)

```
$ cat script.awk
$1 == 123 && $5 == "/usr/test/1" { 
  if (Min == "" || Min > $4) { Min = $4 }
  if (Max == "" || Max < $4) { Max = $4 }
}
END {
  if (Min == "") { exit; }
  printf "The Min is %d ,Max is %d\n",Min,Max}
}
$ awk -f script.awk testdata.txt
```

Comment: Your code would work the same way without `BEGIN { Min = ""; Max = ""; }`. Add a `\n` at the end of the printf so the output is a valid text file.

Comment: I make the initialization to guard against negative inputs (though that might be unnecessary here), since `"" < -5"` seems to be false. (Empty strings, I believe, are treated like 0 in an arithmetic context.)

Comment: Right, it's not necessary since the first time it's seen `Min` is an undefined variable and so has the value of `0-or-null` and so WILL be considered equal to `""` (and equal  to `0` too) whereas after it gets assigned a numeric value it's a "strnum" and so in a context where it's being compared to a literal string `""` a string comparison will be used as you're effectively telling awk to treat `Min` as a string for that comparison, and the string `"0"` is not equal to the string `""`. You could change `Min == ""` to `NR == 1` if you weren't convinced.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
awk '{if ($1 == 123 && $5 == "/url/test/1") {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 }}' testdata.txt
```

is more simply written:

```
awk '$1==123 && $5=="/url/test/1" {print}' testdata.txt
```

or even just:

```
awk '$1==123 && $5=="/url/test/1"' testdata.txt
```

---

You can use the negation of that to skip records you don't care about, then do the min/max tests:

```
awk '
    !( $1==123 && $5=="/url/test/1" ) { next }
    !n++ { Min=Max=$4; next }
    Min>$4 { Min=$4 }
    Max<$4 { Max=$4 }
    END { printf "Number of /url/test/1 = %d with a Time; Min: %d Max:%d\n", n,Min,Max }
' testdata.txt
```

Comment: When I run the complete command at the end I get a result of Number of /usr/test/1 = 0 with a Time; Min: 0 Max:0 - Was expecting Number of /usr/test/1 = 3 with a Time; Min: 10 Max: 30 ?

Comment: I have also noticed I have to put brackets around the awk 'function'  to get an output ie awk '$1==123 && $5=="/usr/test/1"' testdata.txt BECOMES  awk '($1 == 123 && $5 == "/url/test/1")' testdata.txt

Comment: Hi ya - I got this working.  My data is URL not USR